# Difference between (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); and malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Tags: c

The result is the same but I want to know the difference of these two

```
struct NODE * n1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct NODE * n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Comment: You have `struct NODE*` and `struct Node`. Which one is it?

Comment: There's no functional difference whatsoever. https://godbolt.org/z/d9G7rq